# Associating previous records from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a certain query in MySQL, and I hope someone can help me.

A little background info:

We have a callcenter reporting API available to us, from our "telephony as a service" company.  The pertinent fields I'm grabbing from their XML interface are:

- agent_name
- interaction_id
- origination           <-- this is the "caller ID", which is not always accurate
- create_timestamp
- accept_timestamp
- abandon_timestamp
- queue_id

Regular phone calls (interactions, in this case) are answered by each agent, after having queued in our "Main" queue.  The create_timestamp field is the time the call starts queuing to agents belonging to "Main", and the accept_timestamp is the time when the agent answers the call.  The abandon_timestamp is the time the caller gets tired of queuing and 1) hangs up, or 2) presses a menu option to go to voicemail.  The voicemail is saved as an .mp3 file and is queued to the same group of agents as if it were a new, inbound call, except it is associated with the "Main_VM" queue rather than the "Main" queue.

The tricky part is this:

If a call comes in and is "abandoned" to voicemail, the interaction_id does not stay the same for the voicemail .mp3 that queues to the agents.  Nor is it always incremented by 1 ... there are times when other calls come in during the time the person has been queuing.  Here are example record snippets:

```
A)
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| interaction_id | origination  | create_timestamp    | accept_timestamp    | abandon_timestamp   | queue_id      |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|          21771 | NNNPPPXXXX   | 2012-09-04 08:26:15 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2012-09-04 08:27:17 | Main          |
|          21772 | NNNPPPXXXX   | 2012-09-04 08:27:44 | 2012-09-04 08:32:07 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Main_VM       |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+

B)
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| interaction_id | origination  | create_timestamp    | accept_timestamp    | abandon_timestamp   | queue_id      |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|           2195 | AAAAAAAAAA   | 2011-10-28 09:21:02 | 2011-10-28 09:23:50 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Main          |
|           2197 | NNNPPPXXXX   | 2011-10-28 09:22:37 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2011-10-28 09:26:42 | Main          |
|           2199 | BBBBBBBBBB   | 2011-10-28 09:23:38 | 2011-10-28 09:27:23 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Main          |
|           2200 | CCCCCCCCCC   | 2011-10-28 09:24:40 | 2011-10-28 09:33:09 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Main          |
|           2201 | NNNPPPXXXX   | 2011-10-28 09:27:16 | 2011-10-28 09:42:28 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Main_VM       |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

In MySQL, I need to be able to associate interaction_id 2197 with 2201, and 21771 with 21772, for example.  I'll be doing things like `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` to calculate the "total" time to answer the call, SLA met & abandoned percentages, ...etc.; while also accounting for hours of operation and holidays.  I think I have most of that worked out, but my main trouble is what I've just described.

NOTE: I intend to change the "0000-00-00 00:00:00" timestamps to NULL.  I'm still in planning.

Comment: In case it matters, interaction_id is primary and INT.

Comment: What about a `parent_interaction_id` column, that references the "original" interaction?

Comment: That's perfect Vapire, but I need help identifying _which_ interaction is the parent.

Comment: I think it's not really clear WHAT you are looking for... Do you need help programming the logic that finds a parent interaction on a given child interaction? Or do you need help designing the DB schema for a scenario like this...

Comment: I need help building a query to find the parent interaction given a voicemail (child interaction).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made some headway on this, and I thought I'd share.  I just had one of the fields return the most recent call, using a `LIMIT 1`:

```
select interaction_id, origination, create_timestamp, accept_timestamp, abandon_timestamp, queue_name, parent_call, agi.agent_name
from (
    (
    select interaction_id, origination, create_timestamp, accept_timestamp, abandon_timestamp, queue_name,
      (
      select interaction_id
      from queue_interactions q1
      where q1.origination = q2.origination
            and ABS(timestampdiff(SECOND, q1.abandon_timestamp, q2.create_timestamp)) < 180
      order by q2.abandon_timestamp
      LIMIT 1
      ) as parent_call
      from queue_interactions q2
      where q2.queue_name = "Service Desk VM"
      )
      UNION
      (
      select interaction_id, origination, create_timestamp, accept_timestamp, abandon_timestamp, queue_name, NULL as parent_call
      from queue_interactions q3
      where q3.queue_name = "Service Desk"
      ) 
) a natural left join agent_interactions agi
order by a.create_timestamp
;
```